# Mysterious white gap below footer

Tags: html, css

[My page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/shops-and-shopping/clothing-alterations-and-repairs/the-zip-yard-brentwood-595.html) has a white gap at the end of the footer, but after trying everything I could think I'm still at a loss.

Due to the fixed right nav and fluid middle container, we're using a 'push' class and negative margins to achieve equal columns which might be affecting it.

Here's the CSS:

```
#main-content {
margin: 0 5% -100px;
min-width: 960px;
max-width: 1137px;
overflow: hidden;
min-height: 100%;
}

.right-nav {
float: right;
width: 31.5%;
border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
padding-top: 1.5em;
padding-bottom: 10040px;
margin-bottom: -10040px;
width: 358px;
}

#middle {
width: 67.2%;
height: 100%;
padding: 1.5em 1.2% 15px 0;
margin-bottom: 3em;
width: auto;
margin-right: 358px;
}

#footer-wrapper, #push {
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#footer-wrapper {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
border-top: 1px solid #323232;
padding: 20px 0 0;
background: #33383C;
background: #3F4952 url("/images/bg.jpg") repeat;
}
```

Comment: No such gap when using Opera. Have you tried validating your markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetworkNerds solution will work, though I am not a fan of using negative values for positioning.  I would recommend this instead:

```
#footer-wrapper {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #323232;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    background: #33383C;
    background: #3F4952 url("/images/bg.jpg") repeat;
    position: absolute; /*This will set the position*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, `#_atssh` (div with id "_atssh") is the culprit, even though its position is set to absolute, and visibility is hidden. Instead, add the style `display: none`.

This is certainly interesting, and I'll continue to investigate.

Comment: The following is unrelated. Note that http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/css/small-screens/middle2.css is being referenced, but doesn't exist on your server.

Also, line 13 on http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/js/DirectoryBrowser.js is referencing newContent, which is undefined.

Comment: Or, if `visibility:hidden` is required, setting an explicit `top` of 0 works too.

Answer (score 1):

The `#_atssh` div is causing this for some strange reason, two solutions ...

First is `#_atssh{display:none;}`

Second you could move it up a few pixels `#_atssh{bottom:10px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quick way to remove the extra pixel at the bottom of the page:

```
#footer-wrapper {
  margin-bottom:-1px;
}
```